# Bulk API: using Workbench InvalidSessionId (Unable to find session id)

Tags: bulk-api, session, workbench

I'm following this (Bulk Api) [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/api_basics/units/api_basics_bulk), I have valid SessionId and when I try to authenticate I'm getting the following error:

I have created few records using the same SessionId and I know its a valid SessionId and I'm not sure what else is the issue here.

Error:

```
> exceptionCode: InvalidSessionId  
> exceptionMessage: Unable to find session id
```

Workbench:

[image]

Comment: It sounds like you may have gotten logged out of your Org while in Workbench.  Otherwise, once you have a jobId, you can use the same jobId to add as many batches to it as you want but the url needs to be at /services/async/apiversion/job/jobId/batch. You can also query the status of the job or close the job if you have the jobid.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue in Workbench. I haven't logged out of my org, but I still receive the same error message about the session ID.
I attempted to log all the way out, and log in again, but to no avail. I even used 3 different browsers, but no luck.

Comment: Did this error resolved? I do get this error even after trying the way @suresh mentioned

Comment: I'm not sure what I did but after couple of days I able to complete the trailhead, I'm thinking maybe you need to clear your cache and restart your computer and try?

Comment: one thing worth noting is that the URL actually needs to be `37` instead of `v37`... It's different from the `services/data/` versioning for some reason

Answer (score 2):

[image]Session id should be in same row in workbench request headers. Please make sure login to developer session and try with this

X-SFDC-Session:00D36000000qbjo!ARoAQKiXWkLN9KMUcrhH8J11saoMuhArYs8JiYpo.WmGWCmPCNrDFS8riEl08mXy.mwC5XgexaZvnRHMSwb27VHIHxjcKSYu

Thanks
Suresh

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing token, try passing running user sessionId in 'X-SFDC-Session'. It worked for me.

System.debug(UserInfo.getOrganizationId().substring(0, 15) + '***' +  UserInfo.getSessionId().substring(15));

your sessionId is after the *** just to differentiate from OrgId to sessionId